# How to reset the cumulative sum once the sequence is no longer repeated - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as below where I grouped by A and B and performed a cumsum and assign it as column C. But the issue is, whenever I do the cumsum, the value is not getting resetted.

```
A   B   Cumsum
1   2   0
1   2   1
1   2   2
1   2   3 
2   3   3
1   2   4
```

By right , the last row will have to reset to 0. Please let me know how I can do this in pandas

Comment: What are you summing? If you group by A _and_ B there's no column to add unless you're adding the Cumsum column?

Comment: Yes i am grouping my A and B and performing cumsum operation.

Comment: So you're summing the Cumsum column? cumsum is a cumulative summing operation you have to have values to add together. What values are you adding was the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another group variable which detects if any value in `A` or `B` has changed:

```
df['cumcount'] = df[['A', 'B']].diff().ne(0).any(axis=1).cumsum().pipe(
    lambda s: s.groupby(s).cumcount()
)

df
   A  B  Cumsum  cumcount
0  1  2       0         0
1  1  2       1         1
2  1  2       2         2
3  1  2       3         3
4  2  3       3         0
5  1  2       4         0
```

To handle types other than numeric, you can use shift and explicit comparison for `diff`:

```
(df[['A', 'B']] != df[['A', 'B']].shift()).ne(0).any(1).cumsum().pipe(
    lambda s: s.groupby(s).cumcount()
)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: How can I deal when column A and B are strings ?

Comment: Updated with a generic solution -

Comment: (df['A'] != df['A'].shift()).ne(0).any(1).cumsum().pipe(
    lambda s: s.groupby(s).cumcount()) .. If I perform this, I am getting key axis no axis = 1. The thing I am using 1 column for comparison is based on my problem statement

Comment: if you have only one column, then you don't need   any.

Answer (score 1):

We can combine them into `tuple`

```
s = df[['A','B']].apply(tuple,1)
df['new'] = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
Out[100]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```